# mongodb cannot get count on search results

Tags: mongodb

I have a large collection around 200m docs.  I have a text index on it and basic searches like:

```
db.MyCol.find({$text: { $search : "word" }})
```

work fine and complete in a few seconds.

However, certain operations take an indefinite amount of time.  For instance if I want to page the results so I try to get a total count like:

```
db.MyCol.find({$text: { $search : "word" }}).count()
```

Then this just never completes.  I have waited an hour and then given up.  I need this data within the scope of a request.  Ideally a few seconds at worst a few minutes.

I tried to explain the query to see what is happening but I get exactly the same deal, it just sits there spinning when I try:

```
db.MyCol.find({$text: { $search : "word" }}).explain()
```

or

```
db.MyCol.find({$text: { $search : "word" }}).count().explain()
```

I have also tried following a question to get it via aggregation:

```js
db.MyCol.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "word" } } },
     { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum:1 } } }
   ], { "allowDiskUse" : true }
)
```

But again it just takes seemingly forever to complete.

How do I paginate a text search on a large collection?

Answer (score 0):

see if a $facet could perform better

```
db.MyCol.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": { "$text": { "$search": "word" } }
        },
        {
            "$facet": {
                "count": [
                    {
                        "$count": "count"
                    }
                ],
                "items": [
                    {
                        "$skip": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "$limit": 100
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I have left it to run a while and still not finished

Comment: @Guerrilla does you text index fit in RAM? or does it get swapped in/out to disk? if so, that could be your problem. in which case, you'll have to either shard the collection or add more RAM. or prune old unneeded data from the collection to bring the size down.

Comment: I have already pruned data.  Database is ~900gb and text index is ~13gb.  Server has 32gb ram.  I only have to enable write to disk on sort operations.

Comment: @Guerrilla ~40% RAM taken up by a single index doesn't sound good. that + other indexs and working set must be forcing your server to swap to disk. does the disk IO go crazy once you issue the query? and what type of disk is it, ssd or spinning disk?

Comment: CPU is hardly moving, 6% on one core.  Ram is 50% consumed, IO is 95%.  I am not sure what HD it is but probably not SSD.  Unfortunately I am unable to swap hardware.

Comment: Even accounting for a faster HD it wouldn't be fast enough.  I need to get a count in a few seconds/minutes.  For most database systems this is a regular thing but mongo is taking a really long time.

Comment: @Guerrilla 95% IO might indicate the problem. if the whole index was being accessed from RAM (as it should) you wouldn't see that level of IO i think. maybe talk to mongodb support regarding this. if you ever figure this out, pls update the question for the benefit of the masses. good luck!

Comment: I deleted all indexes apart from text index and monitored ram.  It only has 50% usage and doesn't hit swap.  What it looks like is the text index is not being used for count operations